# How to find the new address of a function on a new version of the same assembly with IDA?

Tags: ida, address

Well, I have the old version of an assembly with a mapped address to a function I need to detour.

The developer has stopped the reverse engineering to that assembly, so now, I want to do his job. But Idk where to start. I'm very newbie on this bussiness.

I have downloaded IDA, and I have subroutine calls on the assembly language. but I don't know how to continue.

I already have checked for the hexadecimal but this trick didn't worked on the new version.

So, what tricks do you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

[BinnDiff](https://www.zynamics.com/bindiff.html) and [Diaphora](https://github.com/joxeankoret/diaphora) do exactly what you ask.